# How do I fix a weird rectangle appearing after I remove an entry widget in my Tkinter program?

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I´m creating an interactive board programm and I run into a problem.

After I´m destroying `entry` I have a weird rectangle in the place of previous `entry`. Do I only have this problem? I'm using windows.

Here's my code:

```
from customtkinter import *

set_appearance_mode('System')
set_default_color_theme('dark-blue')

window = CTk()  # Window
window.geometry("800x520")

def destroy(event):
    event.widget.destroy()

def text(event):
    entry = CTkEntry(window, width=100, font=('Arial', 24), text_color='black')
    entry.bind("<Button-3>", destroy)
    canvas.create_window(event.x, event.y, window=entry)

canvas = CTkCanvas(window, bg='white', bd=2, relief=SUNKEN, height=430, width=700)
canvas.place(x=60, y=50)
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", text)

window.mainloop()  # Loop
```

I think I have problems because of line `canvas.create_window(event.x, event.y, window=entry)`, but in my programm I cannot delete this line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `CTkEntry` widget is more than a single widget, it's a frame with a `CTkCanvas` and an `Entry` widget. Your binding only destroys the inner `Entry` widget.

A simple solution is to add a binding that destroys the frame when the entry widget is destroyed, with something like `entry.bind("<Destroy>", lambda event: entry.destroy())`:

```
def text(event):
    entry = CTkEntry(window, width=100, font=('Arial', 24), text_color='black')
    entry.bind("<Button-3>", destroy)
    entry.bind("<Destroy>", lambda event: entry.destroy())
    canvas.create_window(event.x, event.y, window=entry)
```

Comment: Why don't just use `entry.bind("<Button-3>", lambda event: entry.destroy())` instead of binding extra event?

Comment: @acw1668: you could do that, too.